# AWS RDS CPU Quota per Application

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When there's a single RDS serving multiple applications, is it possible to introduce quotas in RDS to limit let's say application `A` to `<= 40%`, and application `B` to `<= 80%` of the rest?

```
cpu(A) <= 0.4
cpu(B) <= 0.8 * (1 - cpu(A))
```

Answer (score 1):

No. this is not possible. RDS does not support this. You will have to implement some logic in the application level.

What I can think is to implement a queuing mechanism in the applications level. you can queue the requests that runs CPU intensive queries and complete the requests in a first in first out basis. Since the requests are queued, you can control the concurrent requests using the queue. Amazon has a queue service called SQS